# Segmentation fault when swapping with pointers

Tags: c

When the program is complied it shows no syntax error but when I try to debug it segmentation fault occurs at line 8 "*b = *a;".

Segmentation fault occurs when we try to access a memory that is not there so I even tried increasing my array size but it did not make any differnece.

I have added my code at the bottom:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
 
  int arr[20], n;

  void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;   //this is where the segmentation fault occurs
    *b = t;
  }

  void printArray(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }

  int partion(int l, int h){
    int piviot = arr[l];
    int i = h+1, j=h;
    while(j > l){
        if(arr[j] > piviot){
            i--;
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[i]);
        }
        j++;
    }
    swap(&arr[i-1], &arr[l]);
    return i-1;
  }

  void quickSort(int low, int high){
    int pi;
    while(low<high){
        pi = partion(low, high);
        printArray();
        
        quickSort(low, pi);
        quickSort(pi+1, high);
       
   }
  }



  int main()
  {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    quickSort(0, n-1);
    
    printArray();
    
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: First of all, please don't use global variables. Secondly, what is the input you give the program? And if you go up the call stack when the crash happens, what are the indexes `i` and `j` you are you using for the array?

Comment: `while (j > l)` cannot be the correct condition in `partition` because `j` increases, so this loop never terminates.

Comment: Swap seems fine. So it must be misused. Misusing it is easiest by giving inappropriate addresses. You only uses addresses of array elements. So misusing them implies wrong array indexes. Insert a print whenever you use an array index beyond 19. Let the program tell you what goes wrong.

Comment: Your `while (j > l)` loop is walking past the end of the array, attempting to swap values as it goes.  You need to ensure that `j` is within the proper bounds.